# How to pass flags to IBM xlc compiler?

Tags: aix, xlc

I want to build samba4 on aix,gcc give me error,so i want to try xlc ibm compiler
But give me this error

```
    "../source4/heimdal/lib/gssapi/gssapi/gssapi_spnego.h", line 49.28: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"../source4/heimdal/lib/gssapi/gssapi/gssapi_spnego.h", line 41.1: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for GSSAPI_CPP_START.
"../source4/heimdal/lib/gssapi/gssapi/gssapi_spnego.h", line 49.28: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"../source4/heimdal/lib/gssapi/gssapi/gssapi_spnego.h", line 41.1: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for GSSAPI_CPP_START.
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/samba-4.0.25/bin'
Build failed:
 -> task failed (err #1): 
        {task: cc dnsrecord.c -> dnsrecord_1.o}
 -> task failed (err #1): 
        {task: cc dnsutils.c -> dnsutils_1.o}
make: The error code from the last command is 1.
```

I search on net and i found

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LI75061

the interesting line is "You can use ‍‍‍‍`-‍qcpluscmt` to have the C compiler accept C++ style"

So i try to compile with those lines

```
CFLAGS='-qcpluscmt' CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/freeware/include' LDFLAGS=' -L/opt/freeware/lib' ./configure --prefix=/opt/mg --check-c-compiler=xlc
 make clean
CFLAGS='-qcpluscmt' CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/freeware/include' LDFLAGS=' -L/opt/freeware/lib' make
```

But give me same error.
What is wrong?

Comment: I think to you need specify more `-I` (header files)

Comment: If i put no header compilation works "fine",or better give another kind of error,i'm tryng to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags are correct the error was to put external headers